# Cannot run java classes of Coursera Algorithm Course

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

More than a year ago I attended the Algorithm I course on Coursera. Now I cannot run my classes anymore. I have seen several posts here but they do not help. I have tried from Eclipse as well as from Terminal but I get errors like:

```
./src/Percolation.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF qfObj = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class WeightedQuickUnionUF
  location: class Percolation
```

or

```
./Deque.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        StdOut.print(i+":");
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class Deque<Item>
  where Item is a type-variable:
  Item extends Object declared in class Deque
```

I used to have imports such as these in my classes:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdStats;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Stopwatch;
```

but they are flagged as errors in eclipse. I have algs4.jar and stdlib.jar in my libraries

Similar classes can be found here: 
https://github.com/zhichaoh/Coursera-Algorithms
so maybe the question is: How to make them run?

Comment: I suspect the solution is that you need to add these JAR files to your Java CLASSPATH

Comment: I tried with this
javac -cp .lib/algs4.jar:.lib/stdlib.jar ./src/Percolation.java
but it cannot find WeightedQuickUnionUF.

Actually I see that a similar command works for a few other classes downloaded from the link above, eg
javac -cp .lib/algs4.jar:.lib/stdlib.jar ./src/RandomizedQueue.java
I have to remove all the import statements, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, In my case the solution happened to be pretty simple. I had to rename the file with the right extension and then rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue in Coursera VsCode toolbox

My Solution:

1. Make class public.
2. Filename and Class name have to be the same, it is case-sensitive.
3. Run in terminal: javac "Class name".java
4. Run in terminal: java "Class name"